# Equivalent definitions of a completely regular space

Tags: general-topology

This is probably a softball question, but I'm having a bit of a brain cramp.

Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space such that for every closed set $F \subseteq X$ and every $x \in X - F$, there exists a continuous function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \notin f(F)$ and $f$ is constant on $F$.

Now, I want to show that for every closed set $F \subseteq X$ and every $x \in X - F$, there exists a continuous function $f : X \to [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f(t) = 1$ for every $t \in F$.

But I'm having a bit of a brain cramp in showing that the first condition implies the second. Any answers or hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a function $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$ with $f(y)=c$ for all $y\in F$, and $f(x)\ne c$. Consider the function $g(y)=f(y)-f(x)$. It's properties are: $g(x)=0$ and $g(y)=c-f(x)\ne 0$, a constant on $F$. Now divide your $g$ by $c-f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, just a clarification: if h is the function that we get from g by dividing by the constant c - f(x), then it's obvious that h(x) = 0 and h(t) = 1 for any t in F. But how do we now that h(y) is between 0 and 1 for any y not equal to x and not in F?

Comment: further adjust your function as required.